# Finding the average of Vectors in a list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a list of Vector3, each with x,y,z values.

```
List<Vector3> list = new List<Vector3>();
```

I would like to iterate through this list, and find the average and create a vector from it:

resultant vector:

```
averageVector.X = average of all the x values;
averageVector.Y= average of all the y values;
averageVector.Z = average of all the z values;

return averageVector;
```

I'm trying to create a function for this, and would love your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use linq [`Enumerable.Average`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.90).aspx) to achive that

```
var newVector = new Vector3(
        list.Average(x=>x.X),
        list.Average(x=>x.Y),
        list.Average(x=>x.Z));
```

`list.Average(x=>x.Z)` will return average value of `Z` from all elements from `list`

Comment: [juharr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33170847/7111561) would probably be more efficient as it iterates the list only once

Answer (score 18):

You can use `Enumerable.Aggregate` to sum up the vectors, then just divide by the count to get the average.

```
var average = list.Aggregate(new Vector3(0,0,0), (s,v) => s + v) / (float)list.Count;
```

Comment: This worked however I used the previous answer. Thank you I tried them both and worked well. Not sure on efficiency on either but will check =)

Comment: @Passy This will make only one pass through the list versus 3 for wudzik's answer.  Either way both are technically linear and wudzik's is probably a little easier to read.

Comment: @rostok, this parameter is unnecessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

A modern code way to solve this is using a Unity `Bounds` axis-aligned bounding box.

Code looks like this:

```
var bounds = new Bounds(Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero);
list.ForEach(v => bounds.Encapsulate(v));
return bounds.center;
```